# Google Cloud VM: CPU usage stats not showing anymore

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, cpu-usage

I used to have a graph with my VM's CPU usage.

Something like this: 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9MIE.png).

Now it isn't there anymore. Any idea how I bring it back?

Thanks